# I'm a beginner and I'm creating a C program to print numbers from 0 to n using while loop where n is input from user

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm a beginner and I'm creating a C program to print numbers from 0 to n using while loop where n is input from user.

```c
//program to print numbers 0 to n where n is input from user

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,num;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(i<=num)
    {
        printf('%d',i);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Im getting error saying expected const char

[image: This is the Error]

I tried to get solution over several websites
since im new to this language I'm facing trouble in such simple code

I tried running this code on several online compilers but everywhere I get the same issue

Comment: You are using multi-character character literal `'%d'` while correctly using a string `"%d"`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Side note: indent your code properly, for example like the samples in your learning material.

Answer (score 1):

In line 11 in the printf statement you have used single quotes - '%d' which does is giving you problems here, change it to a "%d". Hope that helps.

Comment: You should format the question properly. And printf is not a statement but a function and  in answers there is no need for "Hope that helps" and other conversational comments.